# conda: GData and http_interface

Tags: python, gdata, anaconda, conda

I tried installing the latest version of [GData](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gdata/2.0.18) using the latest version of [conda](https://github.com/conda/conda) and  [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/):

> conda install gdata

It seems to have worked.

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    gdata-2.0.18               |           py27_0         765 KB
    python-2.7.7               |                0        10.0 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        10.7 MB
```

However, when I try doing:

```
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
```

I get:

```
---> 33 import atom.http_interface
     34 import atom.url
     35 import atom.http

ImportError: No module named http_interface
```

Why? How can I use it?

Comment: Just tried this myself, seems to work to me. Are you sure that the python interpreter you wrote this command inside was the conda Python? What system are you on? Can you try `which python`?